# What is the purpose of sqlite3_win32_set_directory / SQLite3.SetDirectory?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

Hi, I have installed the sqlite-net nuget package, which comes with 2 cs files: SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs.

`SQLite.cs` contains a class called `SQLite3` which contains the method:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_win32_set_directory", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SetDirectory(uint directoryType, string directoryPath);
```

I see that the `SQLiteConnection` constructor has the following code:

```
#if NETFX_CORE
         SQLite3.SetDirectory(/*temp directory type*/2, Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path);
#endif
```

But **why**?! What does this do and why does it need to be set each time a new SQLiteConnection is created? It seems like I get sporadic `AccessViolationExceptions` with this line.

### Update

I found the documentation for this method but still don't understand the purpose of the TempDirectory. What gets written there?

```
/*
** This function sets the data directory or the temporary directory based on
** the provided arguments.  The type argument must be 1 in order to set the
** data directory or 2 in order to set the temporary directory.  The zValue
** argument is the name of the directory to use.  The return value will be
** SQLITE_OK if successful.
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific call that you show from the `SQLiteConnection` constructor sets the temporary directory for SQLite. This is the directory that SQLite uses for temporary/ working storage.

I believe that because of app sandboxing, SQLite is unable to write to the default temp directory; this is why the code that you quoted uses the application's temp directory.

If the directory is not set, the side effect is that you get errors when executing update statements.

See more here:

- Stack Overflow post - [multiple update statements throw "cannot open"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705341/multiple-update-statements-throw-cannot-open)
- [GitHub conversation regarding the bug and resolution](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/78)

Comment: Thank you for providing those insightful links. What I am now wondering is if this has to be set each time we create a new SQLiteConnection. Isn't it enough to set the temp directory once? Or does that value reset itself when the current connection closes?

Comment: The docs are non-existent on this so I am taking an educated guess. In looking at the SQL-Net source code, the temp directory is set prior to establishing any kind of connection. This would lead me to believe that it is not based on connection, and that the temp directory only needs to be set once. Of course you'll want to test this and make sure.

Comment: This is the best that I could find: http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/20f184f2d5908badd9d44d4fe2ad7c9e182c8803 but I think you are correct. I added a "IsTempDirSet" property to SQLite3. I will test this as soon as I can. Thanks!